# dumping XML log files into Splunk

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, splunk

I want to dump the following XML log file in Splunk keeping in mind the fact that it should give all the tags as a fields such that I could search the events where

Text="Application: Directory started" Category="BIG" Module="WorkflowHost"

What should I write in props.conf

```
<Message>
  <ID>
    b476f836-36dd-4c30-9a8e-0587c5d34b8d-
  </ID>
  <Date>
    2014-01-09 10:45:31.69
  </Date>
  <Text>
    Application: Directory started
  </Text>
  <Category>
    BIG
  </Category>
  <Source>
    Workflow
  </Source>
  <Level>
    Event
  </Level>
  <Class>
    General
  </Class>
  <Module>
    WorkflowHost
  </Module>
  <LineNumber>
    0
  </LineNumber>
  <ProcessID>
    5420
  </ProcessID>
  <User>
    e2ac3262e9b9d03f
  </User>
</Message>


<Message>
  <ID>
    b476f836-36dd-4c30-9a8e-0587c5d34b8d
  </ID>
  <Date>
    2014-01-09 10:45:41.57
  </Date>
  <Text>
    Application: PatientDirectory started
  </Text>
  <Category>
    BIG
  </Category>
  <Source>
    PatientDirectory
  </Source>
  <Level>
    Event
  </Level>
  <Class>
    General
  </Class>
  <Module>
    PatientDirectory
  </Module>
  <LineNumber>
    0
  </LineNumber>
  <ProcessID>
    2180
  </ProcessID>
  <User>
    e2ac3262e9b9d03f
  </User>
</Message>
```

PLs help....:)

Answer (score 1):

In your props.conf stanza for the sourcetype you're indexing, add

```
KV_MODE=xml
```

This will automatically extract all the fields and values.

You can find more details in the props.conf file documentation here:

```
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/propsconf
```